# How to change the text cursor in Squeak or Pharo?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak, pharo, morphic

I would like to configure a boxed text cursor without blinking, it is possible in Squeak or Pharo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pharo 1.2 and later: "Settings Browser > Code Browser > Editing" has various preferences related to the cursor: "Blinking text cursor", "Dumbbell-shaped text cursor", and "Walk along displayed line".

Additionally you can change the color of the cursor by evaluating "NewParagraph insertionPointColor: Color red", not sure why there is no setting.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the shape of cursor could be changed. I did this before.

The code to render a cursor is located in

NewParagraph>>displaySelectionInLine: line on: aCanvas 
(see the code below     selectionStart = selectionStop  ifTrue: [... )

Answer (score 0):

I am sure you  can (becasue some time ago it was without bliking), but I have no idea how hahaha. Check the methods #onBlinkCursor and all those in the category bliking in the class TextMorph.

In adddition see: http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=1039